# Ruby implementing access to members of collection by []

Tags: ruby, member

Is there any way to implement access to member of collection by []. I mean i have to program a linked list and i wanna access members by Coll[int]. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you please post relevant extracts of your linked list implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your linked list its own class?  If so, you can define the `[]` method for that class:

```
class LinkedList

  ...

  def [](int index)
    node = @head
    index.times do
      node = node.next
    end
    node
  end

end
```

This code presumes that the member variable `@head` references the first entry in the list, and that the method `#next` returns the next entry in the list.  It assumes zero-based indexing, and has no error handling for the index being out of range.

In use, you call it the way you want:

```
linked_list[2]
```

Ruby treats this just as though you had written:

```
linked_list.[](2)
```

These two syntaxes are equivalent, but one normally writes the first, shorter form.

Comment: ok but won't i need to call it like [](7)?

Comment: @user2184057, I've added an explanation of how it's called.

Comment: Thank you very much i think i got the point :) I thought that i would need to implement one of the mixins :)